# Different view of my contact form from smartphone and pc

Tags: html, css, forms, smartphone

i have this problem: i created a contact form and in my pc it works correctly alsa when i resize the page... when i try with an android smartphone it works too but with a windows phone smartphone it has a different margin, the page is rossimelthomas.com/contact.html
code:

```
    <form action="php/mail_send.php" method="POST">
    <input autocomplete="off" onfocus="if (this.value=='Name') this.value = ''" onblur="if     (this.value=='') this.value = 'Name'" style="border: solid 1px; border-radius: 5px; height:25px; border-color: white; width: 65%; "  value="Name" type="text" name="name">
    <input autocomplete="off" onfocus="if (this.value=='E-Mail') this.value = ''" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'E-Mail'" style="margin-top: 20px; border: thin 1px; border-radius: 5px;  height:25px; border-color: white; width: 65%" value="E-Mail" type="email" name="email">
    <input autocomplete="off" onfocus="if (this.value=='Subject') this.value = ''" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'Subject'" style="margin-top: 20px; border: thin 1px; border-radius: 5px; height:25px;  border-color: white; width: 65%" value="Subject" type="text" name="subject">
    <textarea class="txt_field" style="    color: #99a0aa;margin-top: 20px;  font: normal normal 16px/20px pnova-regular, helvetica, sans-serif; border: thin 1px; border-radius: 5px; border-color: white; width: 65%; height: 300px;" type="text" name="message">Message</textarea>
    <input style="margin-top: 20px; border: thin 1px; border-radius: 10px; border-color: white; cursor:pointer; background-color: #4db849; width:65%; height: 45px; color: white; font-weight: 700;" type="submit" value="Send Message">
    </form>
```

style:

```
input {
-webkit-appearance: none; 
-moz-appearance: none; 
border: 2px solid #eee;
color: #99a0aa; font: normal normal 16px/20px pnova-regular, helvetica, sans-serif;
}

input:-webkit-autofill {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
```

i can't send an image but the problem is only a different view (because the inputs has a 30px margin i think but it must be 10px... i don't know why :( )

Comment: is the `margin` you mentioned is for `form`s only? Are you resetting it somewhere in the code?

Comment: just for all element in the form, how you can see

Comment: can you show where you have reset? fiddle would be best!

Comment: then do a reset, issue you are facing is maybe because the browser is using default reset may be!!

Comment: it doesn't work, other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to normalize the css (or even [reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) it). It's as easy as including one additional CSS file to your project and it will make sure your website is as brwoser compatibile as possible. Check out [this link](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) and keep in mind that just adding it may mess out your current layout a bit, so some tweaks may be required in order to make it look the same as it did.

Also, I can see you adressing some features especially to webkit browsers - please note that Windows Phone's Internet Explorer is not using webikt engine like other mobile browser.